# Disabled keyboard events on React Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following react bootstrap tabs:

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab title="first">
       <ImageGallery/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab title="second">
       <ImageGallery/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab title="third">
        <ImageGallery/>
    </Tab>
<Tabs>
```

The `<ImageGallery/>` component uses keyboard commands (e.g. left & right arrow) to change image. The React Bootstrap tabs component also uses left and right arrow to change tabs, however, causing a conflict.

Is there any way to disable the keyboard inputs on the bootstrap tabs component so that is doesn't change tab when the left / right arrows are pressed?

Comment: "Fixed" this by switching to Bootstrap `Nav` component - doesn't use keyboard commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick solution:
Tabs `OnSelect` method provides two arguments.

1. key (i.e eventKey)
2. eventObject

So whenever user changes tab by clicking on tab, `OnSelect` method receives both argument.(i.e eventKey and eventObject [target]),
But in case the user changes tab using left and right arrow keyboard keys then only one argument receives in the OnSelect method. i.e eventKey

For example :

```
    onSelect = (key, e) => {  
      if(e){
        this.setState({'key': key});
        e.currentTarget.blur();
      }
    }
    // e is undefind when user uses left and right arrow keyboard keys to change tabs
   // e.currentTarget.blur(); //to focus out tab so that page scrolling will work on arrow keys
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same issue and was redirected here. The `onSelect` method from the `<Tabs>` element receives two arguments -- the key of the tab to change to, and the event that triggered the change. When the event is caused by a key event, `event.type == "keydown"`. When the event is caused by a click event, `event.type == "click"`. The following works for me:

```
(<Tabs onSelect={(key, ev) => (ev.type == "click") ? dispatch(...) : null}>
  ...
</Tabs>)
```

Unfortunately, the existing answer above works only because of the blur command -- it isn't actually filtering the events, which feels less clean to me.